# Index out of range on BS4 selecting elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get the ID of the `li` element but I dont want the other elements IDs. I have attached my code below but its throwing a `Index out of range` error somewhere in it

HTML:

```html
<ul class="product-attributes list-inline product-attributes-two-sizes">
    <li class="ease " id="12345"></li>
    <li class="dsadsad" id="000"></li>
    <li class="dadsda" id="000"></li>
</ul>
```

My code:

```py
for size in soup.find("ul", {"class": "product-attributes list-inline product-attributes-two-sizes"}).select('ease '):
    print(size['data-productsize-combid'])
    print(size['data-productsize-name'])
    combidlist.append(size["data-productsize-combid"])
    sizelist.append(size['data-productsize-name'])
```

Comment: soup.find only returns 1 element...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner way of retrieving the information you're after:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<ul class="product-attributes list-inline product-attributes-two-sizes">
    <li class="ease " id="12345"></li>
    <li class="dsadsad" id="000"></li>
    <li class="dadsda" id="000"></li>
</ul>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
item = soup.select_one('ul[class="product-attributes list-inline product-attributes-two-sizes"] li[class^="ease"]').get('id')
print(item)
```

Result in terminal:

```
12345
```

BeautifulSoup documentation can be found [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)